# how to upload image directly on subdomain which is hosted on another server?

Tags: php, dns, domain-driven-design, subdomain

I am trying to upload my image directly to my subdomain which is hosted on another server

currently I am using this code to upload image in test.com to demo.test.com

```
$uploadDirectory = "//demo.test.com/";
```

i use this code to upload my image

```
    $productname="sdf";
    
$member_id="123";

$uploadDirectory = "//demo.test.com/";

$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 

$fn = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$size = getimagesize($fn);

$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height

$photo_name = $productname.'-'.md5($randomNumber.$member_id);

{
    if( $ratio > 1) {

    $width = 500;

    $height = 500/$ratio;

}

else {

    $width = 500*$ratio;

    $height = 500;

}

$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fn));


$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

$fileName3 = $uploadDirectory.$photo_name . '-500x500' . ".jpg";

imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);

imagedestroy($src);

imagepng($dst,$fileName3); // adjust format as needed

imagedestroy($dst);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question ?

The subdomain is usually in the domain layer. This layer must not contains infrastructure logic (call to remote data provider). You shouldn't implement the upload in the Domain layer.

To upload your image, you have to call an interface (method : `uploadImage`) in the domain layer and implement it in the infrastructure (providers) layer.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle